# comm implementation in Java ( comm -- select or reject lines common to two files )

Tags: java, transactions, comm

I have 2 huge files. One of them contains original DB with transactions line by line sorted alphabetically, the second one contains an incremental DB also with transactions sorted alphabetically. What I need is to get all of the common transactions in both files. Is there a fast and optimized way of doing this in Java? Thanks.

Comment: How big are the files? (Will one of them load into memory?)

Comment: the files are not that big and can be fit into the memory